# ASP.net Imitate Slow Connection Speed

Tags: asp.net

Our web application is meant to be run on remote locations with very slow internet speed. We are considering various factors to reduce application overheads. This question is only related to see how our application would work on slow bandwidth.

We are still on development, we would like to be able to browse our web application on speed around 32kbps and 128 kbps on an internet browser, preferably firefox.

Is this possible with firefox to browse a website with max "x" speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I develop primarily in Firefox, so I use the following plugin to simulate low bandwidth situations:

http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx

Comment: This plugin is not supported by new version of firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firefox and have permissions to install plugins, you could use [Firefox Throttle](http://www.uselessapplications.com/en/Application/FirefoxThrottle.aspx)

There are other programs out there where you basically set up a local proxy, send all your connection through it, and have it slow your connection down.

**UPDATE**

Finally found the old program we used to use: [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/)